# Data annotations don't seem to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model Contact with data annotation

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Contact Name")]
public string ContactName
  { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Region")]
public string Region
  { get; set; }
```

I am passing this model as a list in another model ClientModel

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
public string clientname
  {get;set;}

Public List<Contact> contact
  {get;set;}
```

Now in my view I am binding my ClientModel
like this

```
@model MyContact.Models.ClientModel
```

When I submit the corresponding view only clientname comes with a validation message. There are textboxes which are populated from `List<Contact>` but they do not validate. I have copied the required scripts in layout and also have added a validation summary. I cannot understand why the validation is not happening.

---

```
these are my textboxes

<table border="0" id="tbl2" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ContactList.Count; i++)
  {
  <tr>
   <td>
     @Html.CheckBox("chk1", true, new { @class = "BASESAccountTeamChkBoxItem" })
         </td>                   
   <td>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactList[i].ContactName, new { style = "width:170px;"})
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor((m => m.ContactList[i].ContactName)

 </td>
<td>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactList[i].Region, new { style = "width:170px;" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor((m => m.ContactList[i].ContactName)
 </td>
 <td>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactList[i].Email, new { style = "width:170px;" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor((m => m.ContactList[i].Email) 
 </td>
 <td>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactList[i].Phone,  style = "width:170px;" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor((m => m.ContactList[i].Phone) 
  </td>
 <td>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactList[i].Fax, new { style = "width:170px;" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor((m => m.ContactList[i].Fax)
     </td>
    </tr>
 }
 </table>
```

This is the javascript that will add a new row

+Add New Contact

function addRow(tableID) {

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    if (table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML != "") {
        switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}
When i add a new row the validation does not work.I cant know why that is happening 
And i have kept my view in @Html.Beginform only. As my view is huge i am not posting the entire code. I also have the scripts in place .Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a long time ago too, when I started learning ASP.Net MVC3. Here are some tips you can try.

We may be able to help better if you paste your view (or parts of your view) into here as well.

1. Is your form surrounded by a

   @using(Html.BeginForm()){}

   snippet?

   If it's not, and you're doing the form by hand, you may get unexpected behavior with the MVC Javascript validator.
2. Are you including the

   @Html.ValidationFor()

   for each of your text boxes?

   And not just a ValidationFor() the list?